# how to Sorting an array of struct pointers with qsort

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, qsort

This is my `Book` structure and here is my code:

```
typedef struct book {
   char title[100];
   char author[20];
   int price;
} BOOK;

#define MAX_SIZE 10

int comparePrice(const void *bookA, const void *bookB);

int count = 0;

int main() {    
    BOOK *books[MAX_SIZE];    // here is  array of struct pointers
    while (1) {   
        char title[100] = "";
        char author[20] = "";
        int price = -1;
        //////////// printf select menu ////////////
        int selector = -1;
        scanf("%d", &selector);
        switch (selector) {
          case 1:
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            printf("--------input book data--------\n");
            printf("title :");
            gets(title);
            printf("author :");
            gets(author);

            printf("price :");
            scanf("%d", &price);

            books[count] = (BOOK *) malloc(sizeof(BOOK));
            memset(books[count], 0, sizeof(BOOK));
            strcpy(books[count]->title, title);
            strcpy(books[count]->author, author);
            books[count]->price = price;
            count++;
            break;
          case 4:
            printf("--------sorting price--------\n");
            qsort(books, count, sizeof(BOOK), comparePrice);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                printf("%d. title: %s author: %s price: %d\n", i + 1, books[i]->title, books[i]->author, books[i]->price);
            }
            break;
          default:
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i) {
                free(books[i]);
                books[i] = NULL;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int comparePrice(const void *bookA, const void *bookB) {
    const BOOK *a = (const BOOK *)bookA;
    const BOOK *b = (const BOOK *)bookB;
    return b->price - a->price;
}
```

but `qsort` is not working
select number 4 menu and this program stop.
I tried debugging and found that a and b have unknown values.
And `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error occurs in the printf statement to print the sorting result.
What I need to do for sorting.

Comment: pssst, if you use `calloc`, you don't need to `memset` everything to 0 yourself. Any you're forgetting to `free`, so you have a memory leak. And [`gets` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036). `strcpy` is also pretty dangerous.

Comment: nice edit, but there's no guarantee that the `books` array has `MAX_SIZE` elements. So you are possibly trying to free uninitialized pointers. Use `count`.

Comment: @YIGeon Are you trying to sort in the descending order?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `books` should be initialized

```
BOOK *books[MAX_SIZE] = { NULL };
```

Otherwise this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i) {
    free(books[i]);
    books[i] = NULL;
}
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

As you have an array of pointers then the call of `qsort` should look at least like

```
qsort( books, count, sizeof( BOOK * ), comparePrice );
```

On the other hand, he function `comparePrice` should be defined the following way

```
int comparePrice( const void *bookA, const void *bookB ) 
{
    const BOOK *a = *( const BOOK * const * ) bookA;
    const BOOK *b = *( const BOOK * const * ) bookB;
    
    return ( a->price < b->price ) - ( b->price < a->price );
}
```

Here is a simplified demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct book
{
    int price;
} BOOK;

int comparePrice( const void *bookA, const void *bookB ) 
{
    const BOOK *a = *( const BOOK * const * ) bookA;
    const BOOK *b = *( const BOOK * const * ) bookB;
    
    return ( a->price < b->price ) - ( b->price < a->price );
}

int main(void) 
{
    BOOK b1 = { 10 }, b2 = { 20 };
    BOOK *a[] = { &b1, &b2 };
    const size_t count = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i]->price );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( a, count, sizeof( BOOK * ), comparePrice );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i]->price );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 20 
20 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function is incorrect: it gets pointers into the array, hence pointers to structure pointers.  Furthermore, comparing integers by subtracting them does not work if the subtraction overflows which is possible when comparing very large values of opposite signs.

Here is a modified version:

```
int comparePrice(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const BOOK *a = *(const BOOK * const *)aa;
    const BOOK *b = *(const BOOK * const *)bb;
    /* sort in decreasing order of price */
    return (b->price > a->price) - (b->price < a->price);
}
```

The `qsort()` call is incorrect too. It should be:

```
qsort(books, count, sizeof(*books), comparePrice);
```

There are other problems in the code:

- the array `books` is uninitialized so you should only `free` the pointers that have been allocated: change the last loop to

  ```
    while (count > 0) {
        free(books[--count]);
    }
  ```
- do not use `gets()`.
- beware of the potential infinite loop: `while (getchar() != '\n');`
  Always test for `EOF`:

  ```
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

qsort passes pointers to the elements in the array to the compar function (which, in your case, are themselves pointers).  So you want:

```
int comparePrice(const void *bookA, const void *bookB) {
    const BOOK *a = *(const BOOK **)bookA;
    const BOOK *b = *(const BOOK **)bookB;
    return b->price - a->price;
}
```